# Is the upstart online cookbook down? Is so, any backup?

Tags: upstart

Some legacy system still uses upstart, so I still go check the cookbook from time to time. (Used to be at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook)
But the whole upstart.ubuntu.com domain seems to be taken down.
Is the cookbook still available somewhere?

Comment: Ubuntu hasn't used *upstart* in a **long** time... what Ubuntu product & release are you using  (*as no supported Ubuntu system has used it in a long time, it was replaced by systemd **prior to** 2016 or 16.04*) ; it was *deprecated* years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Archive's Wayback Machine has archived it: https://web.archive.org/web/20230322064449/http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/. The cookbook website was generated from code that's still hosted on Launchpad: [https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-documenters/upstart-cookbook/trunk/files](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eupstart-documenters/upstart-cookbook/trunk/files) - so you can clone it using bazaar. The main content is a [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html) file, so it is fairly human-readable, but can be rendered into something presentable by a variety of methods, like Pandoc or [docutils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-docutils). The archived page says that the content is licensed under the CC BY-SA 3.0 unported license, so it should be OK to re-host it on Gitlab, GitHub or the like as long as you comply with that license.